# Reusable operator in rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Basically, i have this kind of logic that is same across all resolvers. I have problem to make it reusable to other resolver.

Here my example:

```
// fetch-abc.resolver.ts
@Injectable()
export class FetchAbcResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private route: Router,
                private ngProgress: NgProgress,
                private abcService: AbcService) {
    }

    resolve = (activateRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {

        this.ngProgress.start()

        const slug: string = activateRoute.paramMap.get('slug')

        return this.abcService.fetchAbc(slug)
                   .delay(1000)
                   .finally(() => this.ngProgress.done())
                   .catch(error => {
                       this.route.navigate([ '/404', {
                           err: 'Error',
                           msg: `Could not find ${slug}`, error
                       } ])

                       return Observable.empty()
                   })
    };
}
```

How do i make `.delay`, `.finally` and `catch` reusable.

my current work in progress is this

```
// rxjs.apply.ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

function apply(functions: Array<Function>) {
    functions = [].concat(functions);

    return functions.reduce((observable, func) => func(observable));
}

Observable.prototype.apply = apply

declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
    interface Observable<T> {
        apply: typeof apply;
    }
}
```

but i'm stuck how to combine the operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using RxJS 5.4 and `patch` style of operators you can use `let` and make a function that takes the parameters you want to make configurable and appends the chain you want:

```
const myChain = (x, y) => 
  source => 
    source.delay(x)
      .finally(() => console.log(y))
      .catch(error => Observable.empty());

Observable.of(42)
  .let(myChain(1000, 'a'))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-zytoqb?file=index.ts

Where `myChain` is a function that return a function that appends operators. It's probably more obvious when I add parenthesis without using arrow functions:

```
function myChain(x, y) {
  return function(source) {
    return source.delay(x)
      .finally(() => console.log(y))
      .catch(error => Observable.empty());
  };
};
```